# Difference between 委嘱状・任命状・任命証

Tags: translation, word-choice

If the talk is about appointing the representative of Internal Management System (IMS) (in some company), which one will be suitable in this situation? :

Letter of appointment (to a position): 
委嘱状 【いしょくじょう】・任命状【にんめいじょう】・任命証 【にんめいしょう】・辞令【じれい】

Comment: Maybe you could add 辞令 to your list.

Comment: Oh, thank you, this one is also very important to distinguish. Adding..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 辞令 is an appointment notice issued typically by a president to his/her employee. It typically looks [like this](http://www.taka.co.jp/download/word/w_zirei_t.html). For some reason it's usually very short, blunt, and not polite at all :)

委嘱 is a respectful word used when someone asks someone to do a job that requies sophisticated expertise. I feel external consultants/advisors are often invited using the term 委嘱. 任命 is similar in meaning but sounds more "authoritative" (both in positive and negative senses). Which to use 委嘱 or 任命 would depend on the relation between the two.

As for the difference between ～証 and ～状, the former literally means "certificate for ～" and the latter literally means "notice/letter for ～". I think I see ～状 far more often, but there should be no big difference in this case.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is so clear... and helpful!!

Answer (score 2):

## English

委嘱状, 任命証, 任命状 and 辞令 share the same meaning.

### Difference between 委嘱 and 任命

委嘱 and 任命 means exactly the same, but are used in different contexts.

If you are hiring someone who is not member of a civil or administrative agency, then you should use 委嘱. (In that case, you will send a 委嘱状.)

If you are hiring someone who is a member an administrative agency, you should use 任命. (In that case, you deliver a 辞令書. 任命証 and 任命状 are interchangeable)

See: [here](http://lawinfo.crestec.jp/faq/?p=44)

## Japanese

それらの意味は全て同じです。

### 委嘱と任命の違い

これらの意味は完全に同じです。ですがこれらを相手によって使い分けています。

相手が民間人もしくは行政機関に属していないなら委嘱を使います。(その場合、委嘱状を交付する。)

相手が行政機関に属している任命を使います。(その場合は、事例書を交付します。言い方を任命証、任命状に変えても良い)

参考:[このサイト](http://lawinfo.crestec.jp/faq/?p=44)

Comment: 相手が行政機関に「属していない」なら任命を使います。 <-- 「属している」ではないでしょうか？

Comment: @永劫回帰 間違えました。編集しました。あと、文章直して下さりありがとうございます。